# Android Studio 4.4.2. Direct local .aar file dependencies are not supported when building an AAR

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library, android-gradle-3.0

Everything was fine, but after the next build I got some errors.

> Direct local .aar file dependencies are not supported when building an AAR. The resulting AAR would be broken because the classes and Android resources from any local .aar file dependencies would not be packaged in the resulting AAR. Previous versions of the Android Gradle Plugin produce broken AARs in this case too (despite not throwing this error). The following direct local .aar file dependencies of the :app project caused this error

`implementation files('libs/lib1.aar')`

`implementation files('libs/lib2.aar')`

I don't have the source for these libraries, so I cannot connect them as modules. How can I solve those problems?

Thank you in davance.

Comment: Put those AARs in a Maven repository, such as `mavenLocal()`, and pull them from there.

Comment: same problem :( any solution?

Answer (score 3):

I got this error when I used the "Rebuild Project" option in AndroidStudio. When I used the "Build Project" options instead the error disappeared

Comment: Is there any way to ignore this error?

Comment: if you need to generate signed apk/aab you will face this error, so this is not a solution.

Answer (score -3):

I have faced same issue,i tried with add module but not working so i changed my build tools gradle dependency version from 4.2.2 to 3.6.1 and this solution is working with if add .aar file in libs folder because gradle tools version more than 4.0.0 is not supported local .aar files.

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'